# How can I get this vertical reverse order of elements script working in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**For any future readers reading this the problem has been solved already the true answer is my answer mentioned below but the rewarded answer is made to derpirscher.**

Without this script the elements order looks like this

```
A
B
C
D
```

This is what I want so with this script the targeted elements looks like this in reverse order for example

```
D
C
B
A
```

I got this script to work in all the other browsers I want it to work on except in internet explorer 11

but in IE in general i'm getting this error

[SCRIPT1002:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/misc/syntax-error-javascript) Syntax error

1.html (57,13)

According to the link that gives more details of the error it says this

***Syntax error (JavaScript)***

```
You created a statement that violates one or more of the grammatical rules of JavaScript.
```

and it is referencing to this line

```
var divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.x')];
```

Here is my code

```html
<style>
#a{
  background-color: gold;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

#b{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.x{
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
 position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
</style>

<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'>
    
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>D</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    
  </div><!--</b>-->
</div><!--</a>-->

<script>
var divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.x')];
var new_order = divs.reverse();
new_order = new_order.map(elem => elem.outerHTML);
document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML = new_order.join('');
</script>
```

So how can I get this to work in internet explorer 11?
Any method that you guys can suggest I will really appreciate that and please don't suggest anything CSS related I am aware that there is CSS methods that can

cause this effect but sadly those CSS methods don't work on certain browsers or on older browsers I notice a JavaScript approach is working for me on those browsers that those CSS methods failed to work on just letting you guys know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 11 does not support spread syntax (`[...document.querySelectorAll('.x')]`) because this was introduced only in ES2015 which was way after release of IE11.

To be on the safe side, you could iterate over the `NodeList` and add the items to your array.

```
var nl = document.querySelectorAll('.x');
var divs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nl.length; i++) divs.push(nl[i]);
```

Or (as the NodeList is somehow similar to an array, but missing most of the functions defined on an array), you could call

```
var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.x'));
```

**EDIT**

As it seems, you have more than just one JS-Version issue, you can also use [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to translate your JS code to be IE compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your response I appreciate it I tried out your response by doing this var nl = document.querySelectorAll('.x');
var divs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nl.length; i++) divs.push(nl[i]);

var new_order = divs.reverse();
new_order = new_order.map(elem => elem.outerHTML);
document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML = new_order.join('');                                     but now it is giving me the same error at this line new_order = new_order.map(elem => elem.outerHTML);

Comment: Same answer. Arrow functions `coll.map(x => x.outerHTML)` are not supported in IE. You are coding following a "relatively new" JS standard, which IE simply does not support, thus the syntax errors. For your arrow functions you will need something like `new_order.map(function(elem) { return elem.outerHTML;})`

Answer (score 1):

This now works on IE. Thanks guys I don't know if I should reward Xhulio Kondakçiu or derpirscher because the

two of you helped me solved this so i'm going to award derpirscher because derpirscher been responding to me more. So here is my answer that worked for me.

```js
var divs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".x"));

var new_order = divs.reverse();
new_order = new_order.map(function(elem) { return elem.outerHTML;});
document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML = new_order.join('');
```

```css
#a{
  background-color: gold;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

#b{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.x{
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
 position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
  <div id='b'>
    
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    <div class='x'>
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->

    <div class='x'>
      <h1>D</h1>
    </div><!--</x>-->
    
  </div><!--</b>-->
</div><!--</a>-->
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like Internet Explorer doesn't support the spread syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax.

So to fix your problem don't use this syntax

```
var divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.x')];
```

Instead, try something like in this link https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array.

Comment: Please don't link to external resources only without providing at least a basic solution. (especially if the solution itself is only a one-liner)

Comment: @derpirscher Why is putting external resource bad? Especially when is a quick read and explain perfectly how to solve the problem and gives a comprehensive information about it.

Comment: Because the link may break (the link may change, the external site may go down, ...). You can add additional information as external reference, but each answer should contain all necessary information to solve the problem. You perfectly described, why the OP code does not work and linked some additional reading. But if your second link stops working, the answer won't help the OP. You could have included a short answer and added a link to the blog for additional reading.

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @XhulioKondakçiu I tried your advice and your advice also worked for me as well thank you but I have a new error it is referencing to the same error but this time at this line new_order = new_order.map(elem => elem.outerHTML);